# How to get DOM elements by class, id, selectors and properties

Tags: angular

How can I get DOM elements by class, id, selectors (`div > .my-i`) and properties like in jQuery?

For example:

```html
<div class="myClass" style="width:200px">
<span id="pop">test</span>
<div>
  <i>aaa</i>
  <i class="my-i">bbb</i>
  <i class="my-i">ccc</i>
</div>
```

I need to get:

1. value 200px by class
2. text 'test' by id
3. all  by class="my-i"

What's the best way?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, doesn't matter, need to get those data and transfer to DB:  200px, 'test' and parse these html objects by class="my-i"

Comment: Why do you need to get them? That seems like exactly the wrong way to be using Angular. Could you give some context to avoid an XY problem? http://xyproblem.info

Comment: @xyproblem.info, i typed above

Comment: *"is it impossable?"* is not providing more context.

Answer (score 53):

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.myClass');
}
```

This will not work well with Web Workers or Universal, but Angular2 itself doesn't provide something platform-agnostic to query for elements.

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Comment: `@ViewChild()` doesn't support CSS selectors, only template variable names or directive/component types.

Comment: Anyone know how to get a DOM element via CSS Selector as the OP asked? As mentioned above, `@ViewChild` and `element.nativeElement` will not work for this scenario.

Comment: @atconway What's the problem. My code shows how to use CSS selectors. What do you mean by "this scenario"? Angular itself doesn't provide anything. If you want to use CSS selectors, you have to use ´nativeElement` or `window`.

Comment: `(renderElement as any)[methodName].apply(renderElement, args);` https://angular.io/guide/migration-renderer