# Set height of div equal to height of window angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How could I set the height of a `div` equal to the height of the window? I've found on this question [Dynamically updating css in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882670/dynamically-updating-css-in-angular-2) saying that I must use code below:

```html
<div class="home-component" 
     [style.width.px]="width" 
     [style.height.px]="height">Some stuff in this div</div>
```

I've update this code like code below:

```html
<div class="imagecontainer" [style.height.px]="window.innerHeight">
    Some code
</div>
```

But this give me next error:

> Cannot read property `innerHeight` of undefined

My questions are now:

1. How could I set the height of the `div` equal to the height of the inner window with Angular and TypeScript?
2. How could I do this in one time, because I've to do this multiple times?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not working because angular2 is trying to search for `this.window.innerHeight`.

Update your component,

```
@Component({...})
export class MyClass {

    myInnerHeight: window.innerHeight;
    constructor(){}

}
```

and use it like this:

```
<div class="imagecontainer" [style.height.px]="myInnerHeight">
    Some code
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying to use `[style.height]`, is there some docs which I can refer to get to know these properties?

Comment: @GiridharKarnik https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#style-binding

Comment: @eko, how about the other way around? Like I want to get the height instead of setting it.

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999988/angular-2-get-element-height?

Comment: @eko, JaggerJo answer works... but it has to be put on OnInit() function not on the constructor. but thank you so much leads and information.

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul glad you figured it out :-)