# Angular 2 get element height

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a really simple example here

Its just an angular app with a single div

Is it possible to get the height of the div in angular

I thought I could do it with @ViewChild and offsetHeight

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './src/app.html'
})

export class AppComponent{

  @ViewChild('content') elementView: ElementRef;

  contentHeight: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  //contentHeight = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetHeight

}
```

Answer (score 36):

The `ViewChild` decorated variable `elementView` is only set after the `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './src/app.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('content') elementView: ElementRef;

  contentHeight: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.contentHeight = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
  }
}
```

See https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#how-to-use for more info.

Comment: If it's static query we can also get ViewChild in ngOnInit hook

Comment: @yurzui interesting! but I don't get it? I thought ngOnInit didn't necessarily yet have all the DOM drawn and only ngAfterViewInit was reliable in this? how are you defining "static query"? if I alter the DOM with my class, then the right value will only be in ngAfterViewInit? how can I know that I'm in a case were I can benifit from ngOnInit's earlierness?

Comment: I am getting this error, how do I fix it? ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '800'.

Answer (score 22):

Depends on what you mean by "height"

### ClientHeight

returns the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin

You could use the [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method after casting the **NativeElement** to **HTMLElement**.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let height = (<HTMLElement>this.elementView.nativeElement).getBoundingClientRect().height
}
```

### OffsetHeight

is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element vertical padding, the element horizontal scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element CSS height. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let height = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetHeight
}
```

make sure yo do this after the size of the element was set (**ngAfterViewInit()**). You can find more aboute [Angular Lifecycle Hooks here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) .

Comment: How would that play out if the display was later resized?

Comment: Thank you for the comment regarding ngAfterViewInit().