# Accessing component's style height in Angular 2/>2/7

Tags: css, angular, angular7

I have found this article on how to set a component's height in angular:

[Set height of div equal to height of window angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334265/set-height-of-div-equal-to-height-of-window-angular)

I am wondering if how can we do the opposite without using ElementRef.

Comment: @TheParam, example please?