# how to set dynamic css style for [ngStyle]

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am looking for setting dynamic css for [ngStyle]
from my component ms-toolbar 
I have set html as

```
<md-toolbar class="ms-toolbar" [ngStyle]="StylingToolbar">
</md-toolbar>
```

and from ts I have initialize as

```
    export class AppbarComponent {
     StylingToolbar = {
    'background-color': '00bcd4',
    'color':'white'
  };
}
```

But on rendering it is not working. On rendering It is setting element as

```
<md-toolbar _ngcontent-alm-42="" class="ms-toolbar" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]">
```

I am using Angular version 2.3.1

Please suggest some better way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically updating css in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882670/dynamically-updating-css-in-angular-2)

Comment: What I want so set object which has css properties from ts file as I described to refer as [ngStyle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have did is right just check your object code

You need to add **#** before color code

Use below code

```
export class AppbarComponent {
     StylingToolbar = {
    'background-color': '#00bcd4',
    'color':'white'
  };
}
```