# pro-grammatically introduce Spacing between rows in angular 4 application

Tags: html, angular

i am implementing angular 4 application. I am trying to display data in tabular format which i have done to some extent but need to introduce spacing in the specific row. For e.g i need to introduce the space after Net Premiums Written. I may have to do it pro grammatically. How do I achieve that.

html code

```
<!-- Card -->
<div class="card">
    <!-- Financial Statement -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="fs_heading">
        <a [ngClass]="{'collapsed': !isExpanded}" data-toggle="collapse" href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="isExpanded = !isExpanded"
            role="button" [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded" aria-controls="nva">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Financial Summary for {{strategyName}}</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div [ngClass]="{'show': isExpanded}" id="fs" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nva_heading" data-parent="#nva"
        [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded">

        <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills financial-tab" id="financial-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a  [ngClass]="selectedFinancialOption===1 ? 'active' : ''" class="nav-link" id="sincome-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" aria-controls="table"
                        (click)="onTabClick(1)">Income Statement</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a [ngClass]="selectedFinancialOption===2 ? 'active' : ''" class="nav-link" id="cash-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" aria-controls="chart" aria-selected="false"
                        (click)="onTabClick(2)">Cash Flow Statement</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a [ngClass]="selectedFinancialOption===3 ? 'active' : ''" class="nav-link" id="balance-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" aria-controls="chart" aria-selected="false"
                        (click)="onTabClick(3)">Balance Sheet</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content Financial-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                <!-- Income table -->
                <div *ngIf="selectedFinancialOption===1 && fsIncomeStatementTable && fsIncomeStatementTable.length > 0" class="tab-pane fade active show" id="base-strategy--fs-statement" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="height:50px">
                                <th *ngFor="let cell of fsIncomeStatementTable[0]"> {{cell}}</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let row of fsIncomeStatementTable | slice:1" [ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[0] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[1] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[2] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[3]}">
                                <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                                <td *ngFor="let cell of row | slice:1">{{cell | shortAndBlankNumberFormat: 2}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <!-- Income table -->
                <!-- Cash Table Start-->
                <div *ngIf="selectedFinancialOption===2" id="base-strategy--fs-cashflow" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab" aria-expanded="false">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="height:50px">
                                <th *ngFor="let cell of fsCashFlowTable[0]"> {{cell}}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let row of fsCashFlowTable | slice:1" [ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] === cashFlowStyles[0] || row[0] === cashFlowStyles[1]}">
                                <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                                <td *ngFor="let cell of row | slice:1">{{cell | shortNumberFormat: 2}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- Cash Table End-->
                <!-- Balance sheet Table Start-->
                <div *ngIf="selectedFinancialOption===3" id="base-strategy--fs-balancesheet" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab" aria-expanded="false">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="height:50px">
                                <th *ngFor="let cell of fsBalanceSheetTable[0]"> {{cell}}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let row of fsBalanceSheetTable | slice:1" [ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] === balanceSheetStyles[0] || row[0] === balanceSheetStyles[1] || row[0] === balanceSheetStyles[2] || row[0] === balanceSheetStyles[3]}">
                                <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                                <td *ngFor="let cell of row | slice:1" >{{cell | shortAndBlankNumberFormat: 2}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- Balance sheet Table End-->
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My current output

[image]

Expected output in terms of spacing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can manipulate the DOM in terms of setting HTML properties and setting CSS styles. If you want to manipulate a DOM element directly you can use

In HTML

```
<input #box type="text">
```

In TS

```
@Viewchild('box') textbox: ElementRef;
```

But this is a terrible approach to styling and to manipulating the DOM in general. What you should be doing if you need dynamic styling is this.
[Dynamically updating css in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882670/dynamically-updating-css-in-angular-2). Use angular's powerful binding framework to do the work for you. You want any property of a HTML element to change? Then bind it. A simple example of adding a css class would be

```
<div [class.col-6]="occupyHalfTheGrid" [class.col-4]="!occupyHalfTheGrid">
```

and in your code

```
occupyHalfTheGrid = true
```

Since you are already using bootstrap, the real solution to your problem is to use Bootstrap's grid system to build the layout you want. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/
 There is nothing really to programmatically manipulate for a static balance sheet such as yours.

If you find that bootstrap's grid doesn't fit you, just use raw css.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp