# How can i set zindex in typescript for angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to set `zindex` for a class using typescript. But it is not working. If you have any idea, please share with me.

```
 ngOnInit() { (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.pagemode')).style.z-index = 1;}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882670/dynamically-updating-css-in-angular-2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) directive for set zindex

```
[ngStyle]="{'z-index':condition ? 9 : 0 }"
```

Answer (score 15):

You might be better using inline style binding rather than using `querySelector` - depending on the situation

```
<p [style.z-index]="1">
  Some text
</p>
```

Comment: I'm a C# developer trying to learn this stuff - not arguing with what you are saying but...why might your example be better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive rather than manipulating the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

**In your Css/Scss file:**

```
.class1 {
  z-index: -1;
}

.class2 {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

**In your TS file:**

```
YourBooleanVariableNameHere : boolean;
ngOnInit() {
    this.YourBooleanVariableNameHere = true;
}
```

**In your Html file:**

If your condition is met:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2' : YourBooleanVariableNameHere }">...</some-element>
```

If your condition is not met: Note that there is `!` symbol with the variable

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1' : !YourBooleanVariableNameHere }">...</some-element>
```

Read [Usage Notes](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#usage-notes) for more examples. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass) for more approaches.,

**Or Alternatively you can try the same approach**, *which is not recommended!*

***Update:***

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("pagemode")[0].style.zIndex = 1;
}
```

[Working example available here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vr5mkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)!

Comment: By typscript...not inline

Comment: The above code is not inline, Its binding! We have written css classes (You can place it accordingly).

Comment: I would say manipulating the `DOM` is not correct approach. Try utilizing the Angular features max.

Comment: gettign error:Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.
any

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176568/discussion-between-rajeshkdev-and-apple-orange).