# Css styles are not applied dynamical using [style.width.%] or [ngStyle] in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using return function to call and html

Return function in .ts

```
 GetHtmlString(user) {
    return `
        <div class="custom-progressbar">
          <div *ngIf="user.HFPassed > 0"  [ngStyle]= "{ 'width':GetFlexValue(user.HFPassed, user) }" class="stat-bar bar-pass"></div>
      <div *ngIf="user.HFInProgress > 0" [style.width]="GetFlexValue(user.HFInProgress, user)" class="stat-bar bar-inprogress"></div>
      <div *ngIf="user.HFTodo > 0" [ngStyle]= "{ 'width':GetFlexValue(user.HFTodo, user) }" class="stat-bar bar-todo"></div>
      <div *ngIf="user.HFExpiring > 0" [style.width]="GetFlexValue(user.HFExpiring, user)" class="stat-bar bar-expiring"></div>
      <div *ngIf="user.HFExpired > 0" [style.width]="GetFlexValue(user.HFExpired, user)" class="stat-bar bar-expire"></div>
      <div *ngIf="user.HFFail > 0" [style.width]="GetFlexValue(user.HFFail,user)" class="stat-bar bar-fail"></div>
        </div>`;
  }
```

I simple set some value in `GetFlexValue(user.HFPassed, user)` like `50` i still didn't get width attribute when i inspect my above `div`

Simple scenario is i create that html inside my angualr material table, and  call that fuction in my td to insert html. Used both `[ngStyle]` and `[style.width]` but of no use...

I am using Angular Material also tried all solution form [Dynamically updating css in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882670/dynamically-updating-css-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

Please use [ngStyle], this will set the width of the containing element to a percentage value returned by an expression.

```
GetHtmlString(user) {
    return `
        <div class="custom-progressbar">
          <div *ngIf="user.HFPassed > 0" [ngStyle]="{'width.%': GetFlexValue(user.HFPassed, user)"></div>
        </div>`;
  }
```

**Reference links** - https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not calling GetFlexValue function as this is complete string.

Also, you need to sanitize this html before using.

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

To do so use as below:

```js
getHtmlString(user) {
  return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`
        <div class="custom-progressbar">
          <div *ngIf="user.HFPassed > 0"
          style="width:` + this.GetFlexValue(user.HFInProgress, user) + `px"></div>
        </div>`);
}
```

Here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spdnvk-c9o9oy)

Comment: Tried that but of no use :(

Comment: Added link now.

Answer (score 0):

How about using  `[style.width.%]="GetFlexValue()"`

i.e
HTML File

```
<div class="box" [style.width.%]="GetFlexValue()" ></div>
```

Component File

```
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(){}

  GetFlexValue(){
    return 50;
  }
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ncr4nf